# Error connecting to ID host: An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: docker, sitecore-cli

I am getting an error when running `dotnet sitecore login`:

```
PS C:\projects\MySite> dotnet sitecore login --cm "https://cm.mysite.localhost" --authority "https://id.mysite.localhost" --allow-write true -t
Looking for package Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Publishing@4.2.1
Looking for package Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization@4.2.1
Finished resolving plugins. Total elapsed resolution time: 100ms
Logging in to environment default...
Logging in to Sitecore. You should see a browser window open shortly.
[InvalidConfigurationException] Error connecting to https://id.mysite.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration: An error occurred while sending the request.
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Authentication.DeviceAuthorizationProvider.RequestAuthorizationAsync() in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration\Authentication\DeviceAuthorizationProvider.cs:line 110
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Authentication.DeviceAuthorizationProvider.Login() in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration\Authentication\DeviceAuthorizationProvider.cs:line 46
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Models.EnvironmentConfiguration.Login() in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration\Models\EnvironmentConfiguration.cs:line 176
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Client.Tasks.LoginTask.LoginWithDeviceFlow(EnvironmentConfiguration environmentConfiguration) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Client\Tasks\LoginTask.cs:line 143
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Client.Tasks.LoginTask.Execute(LoginTaskOptions options) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Client\Tasks\LoginTask.cs:line 63
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Client.Cli.Subcommands.LoginCommand.Handle(LoginTask task, LoginArgs args) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Client.Cli\Subcommands\LoginCommand.cs:line 34
   at Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility.Subcommands.SubcommandBase`2.HandleInternal(TArgs args) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility\Subcommands\SubcommandBase.cs:line 75
```

All of this was working before and I am unable to determine what the specific issue is.

I am running the following:

- Sitecore ManagementServices 4.0.0 rev. 00411.zip
- dotnet 3.1.426
- Sitecore SXA headless 10.2
- All sites (CM, CD, ID) are hosted via Docker
- Sitecore CLI 4.2.1 (4.2.1-r00505)

When I manually navigate to the supposedly failing endpoint `https://id.mysite.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration` I can see that the certificate is valid, no redirects are occurring, and the response body looks valid:

```json
{
    "issuer": "https://id.mysite.localhost",
    "jwks_uri": "https://id.mysite.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://id.mysite.localhost/connect/authorize",
    "token_endpoint": "https://id.mysite.localhost/connect/token",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "https://id.mysite.localhost/connect/userinfo",
    "end_session_endpoint": "https://id.mysite.localhost/connect/endsession",
    "check_session_iframe": "https://id.mysite.localhost/connect/checksession",
    "revocation_endpoint": "https://id.mysite.localhost/connect/revocation",
    "introspection_endpoint": "https://id.mysite.localhost/connect/introspect",
    "device_authorization_endpoint": "https://id.mysite.localhost/connect/deviceauthorization",
    "frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
    "frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
    "backchannel_logout_supported": true,
    "backchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
    "scopes_supported": [
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "email",
        "sitecore.profile",
        "sitecore.profile.api",
        "offline_access"
    ],
    "claims_supported": [
        "sub",
        "name",
        "family_name",
        "given_name",
        "middle_name",
        "nickname",
        "preferred_username",
        "profile",
        "picture",
        "website",
        "gender",
        "birthdate",
        "zoneinfo",
        "locale",
        "updated_at",
        "email",
        "email_verified",
        "role",
        "http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/isAdmin",
        "http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/originalIssuer"
    ],
    "grant_types_supported": [
        "authorization_code",
        "client_credentials",
        "refresh_token",
        "implicit",
        "password",
        "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
    ],
    "response_types_supported": [
        "code",
        "token",
        "id_token",
        "id_token token",
        "code id_token",
        "code token",
        "code id_token token"
    ],
    "response_modes_supported": [
        "form_post",
        "query",
        "fragment"
    ],
    "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "client_secret_basic",
        "client_secret_post",
        "private_key_jwt"
    ],
    "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "RS256"
    ],
    "subject_types_supported": [
        "public"
    ],
    "code_challenge_methods_supported": [
        "plain",
        "S256"
    ],
    "request_parameter_supported": true
}
```

On my ID container, the logs don't show any issues:

```
2024-03-12 09:38:55 [09:38:55] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics [Information] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://id.mysite.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration  

2024-03-12 09:38:55 [09:38:55] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware [Information] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: "IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint" for "/.well-known/openid-configuration"

2024-03-12 09:38:55 [09:38:55] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics [Information] Request finished in 1.3414ms 200 application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

I know that I have all of the prerequisites in place because I have ran:

```
dotnet tool restore
dotnet sitecore init
dotnet sitecore login --cm "https://cm.mysite.localhost/" --auth "https://id.mysite.localhost/" --allow-write true
```

My `dotnettools.json` is:

```json
{
  "version": 1,
  "isRoot": true,
  "tools": {
    "sitecore.cli": {
      "version": "4.2.1",
      "commands": [
        "sitecore"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the following to re-auth:

- Manually log out of and back into CM using admin credentials
- Clear values from `accessToken` and `refreshToken` in `user.json`
- Delete `user.json` file entirely
- Clear browser cache and cookies on ID site
- Flush DNS
- Restart all containers
- Clear browser history
- Add `"dns": ["8.8.8.8"]` to Docker configuration
- Tried it on another machine -- unable to reproduce the issue
- Set `insecure` to `true` in `user.json` file
- Cleared `.sitecore` files and reinitialized

One issue I have seen recently is that certain actions redirect me to the `http` CM site rather than `https`, to which the connection is refused. I can reliably reproduce this by logging out of CM, at which point a call is made to `https://cm.mysite.localhost/identity/postexternallogout?nonce=b19bd38690314aeda5d305cb31e1317d&ReturnUrl=http%3a%2f%2fcm.mysite.localhost%2fidentity%2flogin%2fshell%2fSitecoreIdentityServer` (**notice the http instead of https**).

The `id` Docker logs show this:

```
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics [Information] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://id.mysite.localhost/connect/endsession?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcm.mysite.localhost%2Fidentity%2Fpostexternallogout%3Fnonce%3D547481361ffc4aa89de8a3d0f7eccc33%26ReturnUrl%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252fcm.mysite.localhost%252fidentity%252flogin%252fshell%252fSitecoreIdentityServer%253fsc_bw%253d1&id_token_hint=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFDMzRBQkQ4MUQwMTM1Q0I1ODE3NDY2QzIzMTIzM0M2RUVEMzhGNTFSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsIng1dCI6IkhEU3IyQjBCTmN0WUYwWnNJeEl6eHU3VGoxRSJ9.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.IO7svYjVNt1URpOA7euBchCFhWpDxTOSJLVx3uAmGRS8TiGx7njWhNhezQnaw-9r7WWJMvlMX463EA0ipp-GTHR9BZ3w1r-Wbh7RO1mO2YFGE8q1rTqC1Pytt7_NIKKEehUfj_DJWpe1ApJl-7EH9LKCBuqcDlCWtBQIFExwjVYMl2w-Ficrc-dbzC5rEBWoppnZquQLs9KJddE7QHGme3CpzLeGE4L027A_wUUnckEMVvJqiv1Ly2GVUIjvQgA_pgdIGzo1U8tbajJoBLNXG-5ozaCRSbJvnPoVU4Dkf1t8J8BJ7hou1H-AnbvE68gTr5moxLUkZG0vhbSGx5qgUg&x-client-SKU=ID_NET461&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0  
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware [Information] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: "IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint" for "/connect/endsession"
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator [Information] End session request validation success
2024-03-12 11:19:06 EndSessionRequestValidationLog {ClientId="Sitecore", ClientName="Sitecore", SubjectId="c43a517e91824fe4b4a60e1f13c4f155", PostLogOutUri="https://cm.mysite.localhost/identity/postexternallogout?nonce=547481361ffc4aa89de8a3d0f7eccc33&ReturnUrl=http%3a%2f%2fcm.mysite.localhost%2fidentity%2flogin%2fshell%2fSitecoreIdentityServer%3fsc_bw%3d1", State=null, Raw={["post_logout_redirect_uri"]="https://cm.mysite.localhost/identity/postexternallogout?nonce=547481361ffc4aa89de8a3d0f7eccc33&ReturnUrl=http%3a%2f%2fcm.mysite.localhost%2fidentity%2flogin%2fshell%2fSitecoreIdentityServer%3fsc_bw%3d1", ["id_token_hint"]="***REDACTED***", ["x-client-SKU"]="ID_NET461", ["x-client-ver"]="5.3.0.0"}}
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics [Information] Request finished in 6.6267ms 302 
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics [Information] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://id.mysite.localhost/Account/Logout?logoutId=CfDJ8MlruGwz0zNPpoIZkNeZBloVlWDoECo3fkiHU01_F1gDvuBmAtucXSd6vcgRPPRIux65uXjEsJbq_S7WgO2TJyYDbPpBizg_xi0VjkoizaRxzhJ7LkjwR-QUnUiMIUU7IM1o3Zjxl1sH8L_UBYyE4wU0rPZ1Bmh1msupWIRRkJIn3SikkeuPGjpwZaZ9NoaDTwCA61Vx2sTsCRQelbiTCacxX3I7PeynJjCgc3tO16YAGRwmgvjoHnwliApG3KddZR2Ef72QWHrWVAxE0IyldAwPAbnUt8GieDxp0LFBS9IH3HyoMVsrQG4VD2fXtTobyxKa2ksw5VdMjBdFvPes3M5_c3s-UkZxQ3trUh9G8H8sPOUq44ok-Ye6sf6Vv-yEsUfR0UImiETQTxNw1j4Z9Ntr9tgo5EX-3cKT_lL7dI5aPnXovzqmIYPIpcfv59s5gjg-8rPe-KkjWUxsGxaCilSaVc_mp2_JGqy9mKc7CW0Yjbe_sGpuiIDMZLvvS8fXQmvwB7FyZucWor2NbjjRDuWq7CBSG53utDUMSoq3GEDMLDcNyxkPuJQNQtREjTtQWXWPiLv--hJIto6HNvT1p_R0eXpOMfY6GHGqClnTezEvbv_BsrMJX_04Obh7xbmHfpqvKVTvyZNZ3k02wa6dQNMwbqidJfpr3z3pMMZOPsGCGUGc3_JQv0FOH-X_EOW2WCayxBmvqZHA4p3mzF7mCtbw7UaHGqi395c-9I9OrGU9VY35l0I2EfoQvuG5QhxGXQN_gL09RZQYU2HblAmBBDktemxUkP6fNPhhsDonBy4F  
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware [Information] Executing endpoint '"Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController.Logout (Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer)"'
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker [Information] Route matched with "{action = \"Logout\", controller = \"Account\"}". Executing controller action with signature "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] Logout(System.String)" on controller "Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController" ("Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer").
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler [Information] AuthenticationScheme: "idsrv" signed out.
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor [Information] Executing ViewResult, running view "LoggedOut".
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor [Information] Executed ViewResult - view "LoggedOut" executed in 5.1378ms.
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker [Information] Executed action "Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController.Logout (Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer)" in 13.2591ms
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware [Information] Executed endpoint '"Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController.Logout (Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer)"'
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics [Information] Request finished in 16.8808ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics [Information] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://id.mysite.localhost/connect/endsession/callback?endSessionId=CfDJ.....
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware [Information] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: "IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint" for "/connect/endsession/callback"
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint [Information] Successful signout callback.
2024-03-12 11:19:06 [11:19:06] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics [Information] Request finished in 2.6068ms 200 text/html; charset=UTF-8
2024-03-12 11:19:36 [11:19:36] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics [Information] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/healthz/live  0
2024-03-12 11:19:36 [11:19:36] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics [Information] Request finished in 0.372ms 200 text/plain
```

A potentially notable value in there is `client-ver=5.3.0.0`. If it's what I think it is, it's the wrong version.

Something similar happens when I log in -- I get redirected to `http` via this call after pressing log in: `https://cm.mysite.localhost/identity/externallogincallback?ReturnUrl=&sc_site=shell&authenticationSource=Default`, wherby the response sets the browser location to `http://cm.mysite.localhost/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad?sc_lang=en`.

[image: incorrect redirect to http]

Even if I just navigate to `https://cm.mysite.localhost/sitecore`, I get redirected to `http://cm.mysite.localhost/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad?sc_lang=en`. To actually get the page to load, I need to manually adjust `http` to `https`.

How can I troubleshoot further / fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to determine the root cause of the issue. The only way I was able to get this working was by upgrading to a newer version of Sitecore CLI (`5.2.113`). I spoke with Sitecore support and that was their recommended solution as well.

Recommendation: update from Sitecore CLI version `4.x` ASAP so that this does not become a blocker for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` files, check the environment variables defined for id.

Make sure they are all pointing to the https URLs.

Also, check your `.env` file, and confirm if any variables use HTTP instead of https.

Comment: All of these are set correcty.